# Icons of national flags in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, truetype, nativescript-angular

Is there any lib I can use in NativeScript app to show national flags? `.ttf` would be the best option I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's no where related to NativeScript framework. Those must be simple images you must find in internet. It can't be font as most national flags are not mono coloured.

Comment: It’s related as far as .ttf is concerned I guess. Also by specifying context of the framework I expext unmentioned solutions to be proposed (like use emojis instead).

Comment: There is a complete guide for using custom or icon fonts in NativeScript (https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/icon-fonts). But as I already said, it won't work for national flags as it's not mono coloured mostly. If the purpose is just to use within your app, then images are best solution. Emojis are standard unicode characters implemented by the operating system, there are many national flags already supported in both iOS and Android, checkout the emoji plugin (https://github.com/dzfweb/nativescript-emoji). Guess it has no flags listed but you can always update it's list to add missing ones.